# How to destroy the previous time in the Coming Soon script?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, object

I created a function Coming Soon (the sample is here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_coming_soon.asp). I have two pages that load through AJAX and use this feature to count down to a specified time. Each page has a different date. The problem is that when I go to the next page, the previous countdown is not destroyed and the current page displays the current countdown, then the previews countdown (in one second). I understand that the previous timer was not destroyed, so two are working at the same time.

How do I delete previous data, countdown timer?

```
/* Coming Soon */
function comingSoonInit() {
   if ($('.coming-soon-time').length) {
      var comingSoonTime = $('.coming-soon-timer').data('coming-soon-time');

      // Set the date we're counting down to
      var countDownDate = new Date(comingSoonTime).getTime();

      // Update the count down every 1 second
      var x = setInterval(function () {

         // Get todays date and time
         var now = new Date().getTime();

         // Find the distance between now an the count down date
         var distance = countDownDate - now;

         // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
         var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
         var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
         var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
         var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

         $('#coming-soon-days').text(days);
         $('#coming-soon-hours').text(hours);
         $('#coming-soon-minutes').text(minutes);
         $('#coming-soon-seconds').text(seconds);

         // If the count down is finished, write some text
         if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            $('.coming-soon-timer').addClass('is-end');
            $('.event-time').addClass('is-active');
         }
      }, 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi. We will need to see some of your code in order to help you. Try providing us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, a few seconds!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an "interval" using the function `setInterval`, this function returns a unique numerical value that is the id of the interval created. This id is important because it is used to cancel the interval later, when needed.

So you should store the id of your first interval:

`var idInterval = setInterval(...); // Make sure you can use this value later`

And later, when you wish to create the new "coming soon", you should stop your previous interval, using the function `clearInterval`:

`clearInterval(idInterval);`

Comment: Everything works, thank you very much for explaining. Now a little I had a misunderstanding with the visibility of the variable :). But everything worked out, thank you!